# Chrome plugin says page is W3C Valid, yet W3C validator comes up with 90 errors

Tags: html, w3c-validation

I have been tasked with improving this website (http://www.bdc-construction.co.uk), and one thing I have noticed, is that my Chrome plugin says it's a W3C valid page, yet the W3C validator says there is 90 errors, mainly...

"(http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd) Line 273, Column 28: omitted tag minimization parameter can be omitted only if OMITTAG NO is specified"

I haven't designed this site initially, I also not sure where this error has come from, any ideas guys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think part of the problem is that you are serving something as text/html but your DOCTYPE says it is XHTML.

Comment: thanks for the tip, I have tried copying the content type from one of my valid pages, but that didn't work. Bit of a mystery because I have never had these sort of errors before.

Comment: Try changing the DOCTYPE to just the HTML5 doctype: `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: that definitely helped, so I'll mark as answer. What you suggested isolated 1 error, which involved gZip in the .htaccess file. Thankyou for your help! :)

Comment: Yeah, those xhtml fanatics end up causing more trouble than it is worth.